# there are lots of @Service methods to check if an id has some result

Tags: java, reflection, refactoring

```
if (!WebUtils.isEmpty(appAppService.getByAppid(id))) {
        LOGGER.info(":bind app info");
        errorNum++;
    }
    if (!WebUtils.isEmpty(appDownloadCensusService.getByAppid(id))) {
        LOGGER.info(":bind bi info");
        errorNum++;
    }
    if (!WebUtils.isEmpty(appManuCensusService.getByAppid(id))) {
        LOGGER.info(":bind download info");
        errorNum++;
    }
    if (!WebUtils.isEmpty(appOrderService.getByAppid(id))) {
        LOGGER.info(":bind order info");
        errorNum++;
    }
    if (!WebUtils.isEmpty(appShareService.getByAppid(id))) {
        LOGGER.info(":bind share info");
        errorNum++;
    }
    ......
```

these xxxService are @Autowired properties, and the "...." presents other similar if statements.How can I avoid this by refactoring code?I tried to use reflection to get the xxxService,but I found that the xxxService class could be created,but properties in them,e.g. xxxxDao,SessionFactory(I was using Hibernate),these cannot be created by reflection,how can I 
 do this?Or if there any other way to solve the if check issue?

What I really want is how to refactor the code to make it look more pretty:how can I avoid so many if statements?

Comment: You can mock those service classes, so you can use mockito.

Answer (score 0):

Considering all your classes share the same interface, as they should, you can inject all it's implementations into a List<>. Let's say the interface name is AppService.

```
@Component 
public class Example {

    private final List<AppService> appServices;

    public Example(List<AppService> appServices) {
        this.appServices = appServices;
    }

    public void verifyLogs(int id) {
        appServices.forEach(appService -> {
                if (!WebUtils.isEmpty(appService.getAppById(id))) {
                    LOGGER.info(":bind order info");
                    errorNum++;
                }
            }
        );
    }
```

The interface would be something like:

```
public interface AppService {
     App getAppById(int id);
}
```

And the services:

```
@Service
public class AppAppService implements AppService {
    public App getAppById(int id) {
        // logic to get the app by id
   }
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: oh,that's good for help,I also think of that,but sharing all the classes with one same interface really needs a hard change in the project and I'm not sure weather it could be allowed.Any other suggestions?

Comment: Hum, could you detail a little better how are these classes modelled? Do they have a common inheritance?

Comment: No,these service classess are just seperate interfaces with seperate implementations.

Comment: Ok, and how come they all have this same method, getAppById? I thought they shared something of that... Each class has its own different implementation of that method, with no shared contract whatsoever?

Comment: Because if there's no such shared characteristic, you can't really do anything interesting, and that would be kind of a really bad design... But I'm going to offer another approach more in line with what you where going.

Answer (score 0):

Trying a different approach. The reason you can instantiate the classes but can't have the properties is that you have to get the instances from Spring context, where they're all initialised.

To do that you have to have access to the ApplicationContext, for example implementing the ApplicationContextAware interface.

```
@Component
public class Example implements ApplicationContextAware {

    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    public void verify(int id) {
      MyAppService appService = (MyAppService)  applicationContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().getBean("serviceName");
    } 

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }
}
```

This way you achieve what you were looking for with the reflection methods in your question.

Comment: OK.Nice try.But there is a type cast like (MyAppService) ...,you know my interfaces share no same parent-interface,if I put all the @Autowired service names into a List<Object> and iterate the List,how could I dynamically get the real type of the element and invoke the same method called "getByAppid"?

Comment: Can not get bean using applicationContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().getBean("serviceName")

Comment: Surely I did that :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, let’s if this is what you’re looking for. You’d then have to use reflection.

Merging the answer with application context, it would go like this:

```
private static final List<String> serviceClassNames = Arrays.asList(
    “appAppService”, “censusAppService”, ...)

public void verify() {
    serviceClassNames.forEach(className -> {
        Object service = applicationContext.getAutowireCapableFactory().getBean(className);

    Object app = Arrays.stream(service.getClass().getDeclaredMethods())
    .filter(method -> method.getName.equals(“getAppById”))
    .findFirst()
    .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException(“Method not found!”)
    .invoke(id)

    If (!WebUtils.isEmpty(app)) {
        LOGGER.info......
    }
}
```

Is this what you need?

Comment: thisObject ,this one ,how could u get it?Use the ApplicationContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getBean?Some exception has been thrown saying that no such bean has been found.

Comment: I think I can improve on that, I will edit the answer

Comment: The bean name in the container is the class name in camelCase. Class AppAppService would then be getBean(“appAppService”). If the class is anotated with @Service, they’ll be in the container...

Comment: AppAppService is an interface ,its implementation class is anotated with @Service.

Comment: Then you can refer to it by the classes name or the interface’s name... But perhaps you could do a List<Class> with all the service implementations, and use them to retrieve from the Spring context

Comment: Object obj = applicationContext.getBean("appAppService");NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'appAppService' is defined

Comment: @Autowired
    IAppAppService                           appAppService;

Comment: Hum, I guess you should use “iAppAppService” as the bean name then

Comment: But the List<Class> ideia is a fine one, as the compiler will help you to use the right ones. Then you use the class as the key to get from the container